# Using ycm in vim with python, how to retain the docstring preview while e.g. detailing parameters?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, docstring, youcompleteme

YouCompleteMe is a lovely tool for autocompletion in vim. It also shows the docstring of the 'hovered' autocomplete candidate, which is a very useful tool for me. This preview is sadly closed as soon as one confirms the candidate, e.g. by opening parentheses.

Example:

First Docstring is shown:
[image: Docstring is shown]

Typing a parenthesis will kill the docstring though: 
[image: Docstring is not shown anymore]

Now i would love to keep the docstring while my 'cursor' is in the parentheses of whatever i just autocompletion for (to be detailed: obviously the docstring of the innermost parentheses, if they are nested).

Can this be done, and if yes, how?

Thank you so much in advance, 
LJKS

Answer (score 2):

Add below to your vimrc

`let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 0`

or Default.

The optional `g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion` is `0` by default.

Comment: Thank you, i just copied a line setting this to 1 from a tutorial, and it already helps quite a bit! 
The issue, which still persists is, that i hoped for vim to close the preview once i close the parentheses (have my cursor outside of the respective parentheses) again, is that also possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you out:

```
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 0  " default
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
```

**ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion**:
When this option is set to 1, YCM will auto-close the preview window after the user leaves insert mode. This option is irrelevant if g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion is set or if no preview window is triggered.

Default: 0